# Long text breaks styling

Tags: mdriven

I get different results for same column (static text) depending on having long or short text, why?

Correct layout (shorter description)
[image]
Incorrect layout (Long description in static column)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try to set this css for **.yourclass** text

```
.yourclass p {
   width: min-content;
   min-width: 100%;
}
```

This will force your text to be at [minimum content](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#min-content) width inside .yourclass container. But at the same time will make sure that it will take all 100% of the parents width, without stretching or shrinking it.

Comment: Why is not grid-column 1/14 for description fix this? I added the styling and description and layout is fine now. But still date and time wrap and are also grid-column 1/14 in same container.

Comment: Because CSS-Grid is not strict on column sizes. Turnkey don't have any knowledge about how you want your columns sized. Use Firefox CSS grid debug for better understanding of css grid sizing.